# Htaccess language rewrite rule gives error 500

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess

I am using following rule for my website's language changes but it is giving internal error 500

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}$ ?lang=$1 [L,N]
```

I want to redirect any link finishing with

```
link?lang=XX
```

to

```
 example.com/XX/link
```

My rule is working, when I add ?lang=xx at the end of the link. But it is not redirecting to /XX. Also when I check example.com/xx, it gives internal 500 error.

Comment: _“But it is not redirecting to `/XX`”_ - well why should it, what you have implemented so far, is only the _other_ direction.

Comment: _“Also when I check example.com/xx, it gives internal 500 error.”_ - the first thing you _always_ do when you get a 500 error, is you check what the server’s error log has to say.

Comment: There is no capturing group